# How does `ICoreWebView2` run JavaScript code of a module?

Tags: webview2

Can the method `ExecuteScript` of an `ICoreWebView2` object run the JavaScript code sucessfully that contains `import` statement importing a .js file?

If it is doable, what is the difference and pitfalls we shall be aware of, comparing to loading code that doesn't use `import`?